# How do I remove the empty row and columns from the following output?

Tags: python, pandas

I am looking to export a webpage with ugly code to a nice clean CSV so that I can work with it without getting a headache.
[What I get in my CSV:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VNcqT.png)

I have been reviewing a lot of other solutions and have found a few guides which have gotten me to where I am so far but now I am left with a column of '' and a row of ''. Any adjustments I try to make as to '', NaN, None, etc seem to have adverse affects on the output. My attempts to .dropna() and .replace(...) have been for nought.

```
import pandas as pd
pd.reset_option('max_rows')
pd.reset_option('max_columns')
pd.set_option('display.width', 800)
url="https://www.beatsbydre.com/de/support/service-warranty"
df = pd.read_html(url)

with pd.option_context('display.max_rows', 0, 'display.max_columns', 3):

    df[3].replace(to_replace=r'^Pill XL*', value='', regex=True).replace(to_replace=r'^R.*', value='', regex=True).to_csv("beats.csv", header=None, index = False)
```

Ideally I won't have more rows or columns that I need and I can see the products left with a secondary column which lists the price.

Alternatively I would be interested to know if anyone has had luck with the .replace command and inputting a NaN value. When I try it inputs it as a string and not as the attribute in the dataframe which might allow me more options as to getting rid of empty attributes.

Comment: It may help to actually give an example of the desired and actual output instead of describing it by text.

Comment: I just ran your code and when reading the csv that is produced. The DataFrame actually looks good to me.

Comment: @VnC, I attached a screenshot. It bothers me to see the empty row in the middle and column to the right... You don't have that?